# mysql importing 45MB sql takes forever

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, database-backups, database-restore

I'm trying to import a mysql backup of around 45Mb through phpmyadmin, but it takes forever. I've set `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0` in the config.default.php of my local phpmyadmin installation, but afer two hours it's still running! I can't realy understand why such relative small backup must take so much time. Is there a way to optimise the import process (in php.ini of my.conf) or the backup file it self?

Comment: I guess it depends on the format, but if you can do it directly from the command line to mysql you should avoid phpMyAdmin completely.

Comment: Command line is a good advice, but not applicable because future restores will be made on an online installation and I don't have command line access to that one.

Answer (score 1):

My bet is that Fedora 16 is honoring the transaction/sync semantics and Windows is not. If you do the math, 600,000 updates in two hours is 5,000 per minute. That's the same order of magnitude as a disk's rotation rate.

You can try adding `SET autocommit=0;` to the beginning of your import file and `COMMIT;` to the end. See [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) for more information.

These are the only few options that I could suggest to making it import better. Also, Make sure you should increase the value of `max_allowed_packet=32M` or more in `my.cnf` file before generating the .sql file.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't realy get the Fedore 16 part... I work locally on a MAMP stack running on OS X on a SSD-based Macbook Pro. 
I'm trying the SET autocommit=0; param and will try the other suggestions from the link you sent me. I will keep you informed with the result.
The max_allowed_packet can not be changed because backup is from online installation I dont have access to the my.cnf of that server.

Answer (score 0):

try some number insted of 0 in  ExecTimeLimit.

Comment: Use command line dump -  $ mysqldump -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name > db_backup.sql

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was apparently the phpmyadmin configuration, since command line import took less than 30 seconds and so did the phpmyadmin shipped with the Xampp stack I installed this afternoon.
Unfortunately I cannot really say what configuration caused this enormous slowdown.
Thanks for the help anyway.

Cheers
Roberto